# PDO+mysql -> random deadlocks that require a connection reset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, deadlock

I'm sorry for the long text, I think I suffer from a bug inside the mysql database or inside PDO/mysqli and try to explain the situation as good as I can.
I intentionally did not post code, it's not relevant in that case.

I have a quite busy mysql server with 1000 queries/sec in average and around 1 million connections per day.

**I run mysql 5.5.42 and php 5.6.33**
I wish I could upgrade but it's a production environment, I don't want to risk issues during an update.

I use Innodb as database engine (50GB memory for buffers)

Now my problem is that I have random, repeatable deadlocks WITHOUT having concurrent queries and WITHOUT using transactions.
It affects several tables and scripts.

The Deadlocks happen during INSERT and UPDATE.
I've narrowed down some locations and from mysql theory there can't be a deadlock in any of the cases.
No transactions used, simple INSERTs or UPDATEs on a single (primary) id in WHERE clause.
I understand how deadlocks can happen and none of the cases where I get them are at risk.

I have debugged into the issue as it sometimes causes a complete halt to my scripts.
I tried making a sleep() after Deadlock and just inserting/updating again, however I can do that a thousand times and it won't work, it permanently deadlocks.
If I do it at the same time outside in a new mysql session the query works!

The only solution to this issue is to detect deadlocks, close the PDO connection ($pdo = null;), reconnect to the database and repeat the query.

While that works, it's quite a pain to have to introduce that logic everywhere.

I've been browsing the internet, I could not find anything like my issues mentioned. All deadlocks are usually proper ones with an understandable cause.

**Second related issue:**
This one is more rare but it seems related, it is a wrong DUPLICATE KEY error on INSERT. It happens in one out of a million inserts, so it's really rare.
But in these cases only a PDO reconnect solves the issue.

*I would love to get some input, maybe someone understands the problem or has solved it without a hack like reconnecting.*

To Summarize: No transactions used at all (default auto commit), NO concurrent query, innodb in use, simple single INSERT queries or UPDATE with WHERE id=1234;
The deadlocks do only affect random rows.

It seems to be a bug inside the mysql database, some session corruption maybe.

Here deadlock logs:
The first table does have a deadlock problem too once an hour.
I could track it back to some very simple UPDATE queries that are made once an hour, they take about 0.05 seconds to complete.
And the other error log is there with hundreds of entries, no further details.

```
    RECORD LOCKS space id 1983 page no 32800 n bits 1616 index start of table `db`.`jobs` trx id 2083002285 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
Record lock, heap no 859 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800259d6; asc   Y ;;

Record lock, heap no 860 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800259d7; asc   Y ;;

Record lock, heap no 861 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800259d8; asc   Y ;;

Record lock, heap no 862 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800259d9; asc   Y ;;

Record lock, heap no 863 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800259da; asc   Y ;;

Record lock, heap no 864 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800259db; asc   Y ;;

Record lock, heap no 865 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800259dc; asc   Y ;;

Record lock, heap no 866 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800259dd; asc   Y ;;

Record lock, heap no 867 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800259de; asc   Y ;;

Record lock, heap no 868 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800259df; asc   Y ;;
```

Innodb Status:

```
InnoDB 
=====================================
2018-02-07 17:21:27 0x7f5b0d32d700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 22 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 64463 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 21 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 64472
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 2040099
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 3213946
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 2165320, OS waits 554744
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 40616534, OS waits 873123
RW-sx spins 532360, rounds 9261545, OS waits 97422
Spin rounds per wait: 2165320.00 RW-shared, 40616534.00 RW-excl, 17.40 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-02-07 17:15:05 0x7f5af7924700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2109880254, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 147614, OS thread handle 140029031933696, query id 36166552 localhost website Searching rows for update
UPDATE task SET result_delivered=1, result_data='DISABLED', result_gathered=1 WHERE result_data is NULL AND (assigned_counter >= 4 OR other_counter> 1)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 591 page no 20571555 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `db`.`task` trx id 2109880254 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 24; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8611338d; asc 3 ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00007dc237bc; asc } 7 ;;
 2: len 7; hex 3300070012073a; asc 3 :;;
 3: len 4; hex 800085dc; asc ;;
 4: len 30; hex 226973742064617320776569c39f652042726175746b6c656964206e6963; asc "ist das wei e nic; (total 46 bytes);
 5: len 7; hex 44656661756c74; asc Default;;
 6: len 2; hex 656e; asc en;;
 7: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 8: len 2; hex 8032; asc 2;;
 9: len 1; hex b2; asc ;;
 10: len 2; hex 8001; asc ;;
 11: len 4; hex 80030ea7; asc ;;
 12: len 19; hex 692d3036626437323830373833326335656230; asc i-06bd72807832c5eb0;;
 13: SQL NULL;
 14: len 30; hex 7b22636f756e745f6f7267616e6963223a31332c22636f756e745f637265; asc {"count_organic":13,"count_cre; (total 5060 bytes);
 15: len 4; hex 5a7b3419; asc Z{4 ;;
 16: len 1; hex 81; asc ;;
 17: len 1; hex 80; asc ;;
 18: len 1; hex 80; asc ;;
 19: len 3; hex 80000d; asc ;;
 20: len 3; hex 800000; asc ;;
 21: len 1; hex 80; asc ;;
 22: len 1; hex 81; asc ;;
 23: len 1; hex 80; asc ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2109880252, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 146705, OS thread handle 140028677342976, query id 36166547 localhost ss updating
UPDATE task SET result_count_creative='0'
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 591 page no 20571555 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `db`.`task` trx id 2109880252 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 24; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8611338d; asc 3 ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00007dc237bc; asc } 7 ;;
 2: len 7; hex 3300070012073a; asc 3 :;;
 3: len 4; hex 800085dc; asc ;;
 4: len 30; hex 226973742064617320776569c39f652042726175746b6c656964206e6963; asc "ist das wei e nic; (total 46 bytes);
 5: len 7; hex 44656661756c74; asc Default;;
 6: len 2; hex 656e; asc en;;
 7: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 8: len 2; hex 8032; asc 2;;
 9: len 1; hex b2; asc ;;
 10: len 2; hex 8001; asc ;;
 11: len 4; hex 80030ea7; asc ;;
 12: len 19; hex 692d3036626437323830373833326335656230; asc i-06bd72807832c5eb0;;
 13: SQL NULL;
 14: len 30; hex 7b22636f756e745f6f7267616e6963223a31332c22636f756e745f637265; asc {"count_organic":13,"count_cre; (total 5060 bytes);
 15: len 4; hex 5a7b3419; asc Z{4 ;;
 16: len 1; hex 81; asc ;;
 17: len 1; hex 80; asc ;;
 18: len 1; hex 80; asc ;;\
```

Comment: Dynamically SET GLOBAL innodb_print_all_deadlocks=1;  for a couple hours and post the resulting error.log, please.
Remember after the hour, SET GLOBAL innodb_print_all_deadlocks=0; if appropriate.

Comment: @WilsonHauck
I'll post the stuff in my question as update

Comment: Thanks for the update, is this 2 hours of error.log?  We will also need SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; , entire my.cnf/ini, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck That was just a small part, there was a LOT more, mainly of those "physical" ones.
I'm updating the status in my q.

That query " UPDATE task SET result_delivered=1, result_data='DISABLED', result_gathered=1 WHERE result_data is NULL AND (assigned_counter >= 4 OR other_counter> 1)" is one of those which cause deadlocks.
They are made every minute from crontab.
I've tested it and it takes a tiny fraction of a second to run through.

Comment: It looks like only part of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS was posted.  Now, please post complete results of  A) SHOW CREATE TABLE task; and B: SHOW INDEX FROM task;  for analysis of available indexes.  I take it you are in Europe for the time of day differential.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE task SET result_count_creative='0'

has an opportunity for you to add to the table index for result_count_creative and change your query to :

UPDATE task SET result_count_creative='0' WHERE result_count_creative > '0'

EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ..... should show SCAN used on first UPDATE and no SCAN on second update.  Will avoid many row locks.
SHOW WARNINGS;

immediately in the session will show you how the optimizer rearranges queries.

This will only minimize part of your deadlocks.  Still need SCT and SHIF requested yesterday when you have time, please.